# Find intersection of many half spaces in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, intersection, plane

I am given many half space inequalities in this form: `ax+by+cz>=d` or `ax+by+cz<=d`. I want to find intersection of these half spaces.

For example, lets say I am given 5 half spaces: `2x+3y-4z<=1`, `-x+2y+z<=5`, `2x+5y-2z>=-4`, `-x-y-z<=-1`, `z>=0`. You can see the plot in the left figure (it is in the form of planes), what I want is the right plot.

[image]

Here is the my current Matlab code. Each row of matrix P, represents `a,b,c,d,` and sign function. Sign function is `0` if ax+by+cz<=d and `1` if ax+by+cz>=d.

```
clear;close all;clc;
P=[2 3 -4 1 0; -1 2 1 5 0; 2 5 -2 -4 1; -1 -1 -1 -1 0; 0 0 1 0 1];
n=size(P,1);
[x y] = meshgrid(-10:0.1:10);
for i=1:n
    z=(1/P(i,3)).*(P(i,4)-P(i,1)*x-P(i,2)*y);
    surf(x,y,z,'LineStyle','none');  
    hold on
end
```

Here is the output:

[image]

My main problem is that I can plot only planes, but not half spaces. How to change equality to inequality and plot the intersection of many half spaces?

Comment: Mathematically find the intersection of the planes